# GA-H87-HD3 and Nvidia GTX760

Tags: nvidia

Ubuntu doesn't recognise my GPU, I can see image only if I plug monitor into input on MOBO (I have integrated GPU with Intel CPU also)

- MOBO: GA-H87-HD3
- GPU: Nvidia GTX760

Comment: The ga-h87 series doesn't work with Nvidia GPU, it only works with amd crossfire

Answer (score 0):

If you can open a terminal try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And then reboot, see if it detects your GPU.

Comment: I tried this, but after this screen was black

Comment: OK the only other thing I can think is try sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau to see if the open-source drivers work. If you can log in to the desktop, there's always a log in tty if you press Ctrl+Alt+F6

Comment: On this drivers system show an error and windows and buttons look like old style